# Using F expression on django-money MoneyField

Tags: python, django, django-models

Using Django 1.8.5 and django-money 0.7.4, I would like to update a MoneyField using an F expression to avoid possible race conditions. Let's assume I have a wallet defined as

```
from moneyed.classes import Money
from django.db.models import F
from django.db import models
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField

class Wallet(models.Model):
    balance = MoneyField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default_currency='EUR')
```

The following code to top up a wallet fails with `AttributeError: 'CombinedExpression' object has no attribute 'children'`

```
amount_to_add = Money(amount="3", currency="EUR")
wallet = Wallet(balance=10)
wallet.balance = F('balance') + amount_to_add
```

I also tried `wallet.balance.amount = F("balance__amount") + 3` which doesn't throw an exception straight away but then a subsequent `wallet.save()` fails with `TypeError: a float is required`. What would be the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Since `django-money` 0.7.7 all basic `F` objects manipulations are supported.
It works for Django 1.4+.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving it a float instead of an integer? Try: `wallet.balance.amount = F("balance__amount") + float(3)`

I am not sure why their code doesn't automatically try to convert integers to float's if it that is what it requires.

Comment: Thanks for your answer electrometro, I did try to add a float but it returns the same `TypeError: a float is required`. Also, the whole point of MoneyField is to keep all the operations on Decimal, this error is therefore quite obscure...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using a serializer class, a possible source of problem (like for my case) wasn't due to `MoneyField` but rather due to the failure in serializing `F()` expressions.

```
  File "/home/nponcian/Documents/GitHub/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djmoney/contrib/django_rest_framework/fields.py", line 56, in to_representation
    return super().to_representation(obj)
  File "/home/nponcian/Documents/GitHub/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1148, in to_representation
    value = decimal.Decimal(str(value).strip())
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
```

You can perform the F increment expression through this:

```py
>>> obj = Wallet.objects.filter(balance_currency="EUR").first()
>>> obj.balance = F('balance') + Money(Decimal("12.24"), "EUR")
>>> obj.save()
```

So when using e.g. an `update` in a serializer class:

```py
class WalletModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Wallet
        fields = "__all__"

    def update(self, instance: Wallet, validated_data: dict) -> Wallet:
        # Create a copy to not modify the original validation result
        validated_data = deepcopy(validated_data)

        if "balance" in validated_data:
            validated_data["balance"] += models.F("balance")
            # When the update is performed, the result is equivalent to performing:
            #     instance.balance = models.F("balance") + validated_data["balance"]
            # Or more specifically:
            #     instance.balance = models.F("balance") + djmoney.money.Money("12.34", "USD")

        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

But, calling `serializer.save()` and then accessing the serialized data via `serializer.data` which in turn calls `serializer.to_representation()` which in turn calls each of the `field.to_representation()` would fail for the field `balance` because its value is of type `CombinedExpression` e.g. `<CombinedExpression: F(balance) + Value(12.34)>` which can't be serialized. Note that the expression is what we initially set as the value of the `balance = F("balance") + Money("12.34", "USD")`. As documented, [F() assignments persist after Model.save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-assignments-persist-after-model-save)

> F() objects assigned to model fields persist after saving the model instance and will be applied on each `save()`... This persistence can be avoided by reloading the model object after saving it, for example, by using `refresh_from_db()`.

```py
>>> # Access the balance after the obj.save()
>>> type(obj.balance)
<class 'django.db.models.expressions.CombinedExpression'>
>>> obj.balance
<CombinedExpression: F(balance) + Value(1.2)>
```

To solve this, depending on your requirements, you can just refresh it to fetch its latest value. As documented, the refresh would replace the `CombinedExpression` value into its actual value, which then could be successfully serialized.

```py
>>> obj.refresh_from_db()
>>> type(obj.balance)
<class 'djmoney.money.Money'>
>>> obj.balance
Money('10.28', 'EUR')
```

Which is translated to this on a serializer class:

```py
class WalletModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def update(self, instance: Wallet, validated_data: dict) -> Wallet:
        ...
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        if any(isinstance(value, models.Expression) for value in validated_data.values()):
            instance.refresh_from_db()
        return instance
```

After this change, accessing `serializer.data` would be successful.